# Lazy loading not working in case of nested routes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I have a side menu -

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    public selectedIndex = 0;
    public appPages = [
        {
            title: 'Batches',
            url: '/base/home/batches',
            icon: 'people',
        },
        {
            title: 'Student',
            url: '/base/home/student',
            icon: 'person',
        },
        {
            title: 'Assignments',
            url: '/base/home/assignments',
            icon: 'book',
        }
      ]
}
```

Following is my `app-route` file -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./base/base.module').then((m) => m.BasePageModule),
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'base',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
];
```

Following is my `base-route` file -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'assignments',
                component: AssignmentPage,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        component: ViewAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'add',
                        component: AddAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'upload',
                        component: UploadAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: AddAssignmentPage,
                    },
                ],
            }
           ]
      }
```

Following is my `assignment-route` file -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddAssignmentPage,
    },
    {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewAssignmentPage,
    },
    {
        path: 'upload',
        component: UploadAssignmentPage,
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: AssignmentPage,
    },
];
```

I am unable to understand - 
1. Why does it stop working when I remove children routes from `base-route` as they are already there is `assignments-route` -

```
children: [
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        component: ViewAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'add',
                        component: AddAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'upload',
                        component: UploadAssignmentPage,
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: AddAssignmentPage,
                    },
                ]
```

2. When I use lazy loading in `base-routes` and `assignment-route`, it starts complaining -

`base-routes` -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'assignments',
                // component: AssignmentPage,
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import('./assignments/assignment.module').then(
                        (m) => m.AssignmentPageModule
                    ),
            }
          ]
    }
```

`assignments-route`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'add',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./add-assignment/add-assignment.module').then(
                (m) => m.AddAssignmentPageModule
            ),
    },
    {
        path: 'view',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./view-assignment/view-assignment.module').then(
                (m) => m.ViewAssignmentPageModule
            ),
    }
]
```

I have spent quite sometime on it but unable to understand as what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

The pages you're trying to navigate to need to have their own RouterModule's with at least an empty path defined. From the code you posted it's a bit unclear whether you have these but, for example, for `ViewAssignmentPage` it would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = {
    path: '',
    component: ViewAssignmentPage,
}
```

I'd also suggest modifying `base-route` to use an empty path pointing to `BasePage` as its root and creating another RouterModule for the `HomePage`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: BasePage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```